# Inconsistent numbers of samples in sklearn python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the `train_test_split` method in Sklearn python but the training and testing set are not equal in length.

When I try to run the following code segment in Jupyter notebook it shows

> "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [111, 38] "

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("iris.data")
df.head(5)
x=df[['5.1','3.5','1.4','0.2']].values
y=df[['Iris-setosa']].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,random_state=42)
print("train set: ",x_train.shape,y_train.shape)
print("test set: ",x_test.shape,y_test.shape)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
k=4
neigh=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k).fit(x_train,y_train)
neigh
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Answer (score 2):

Change the line:

```
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,random_state=42)
```

to:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,random_state=42)
```

and you're fine!

As a side note, your dataframe does not have header. So, (i) to load it properly and (ii) prevent from warnings appearing when you fit your model, you should put at the top of your code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("iris.data", header=None)
x=df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]].values
y=df.iloc[:,[4]].values.ravel()
```